# How to create dynamic dropdownlist using jsp and database using only one table?

Tags: database, jsp, servlets

I want to display multiple dropdowns on a JSP page. The first dropdown list showed the data, but the second dropdown did not show the data. The console did not tell anything about it.

database:

`CREATE TABLE "HAI"."SERVICE" 
   (    "SERVICEID" NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SERVICENAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "SERVICEPRICE" BINARY_DOUBLE,`

here the code from jsp:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Select Service Name:
                <select name="serviceName">
                    <option selected = "selected">Select Name</option>
                    <%

                        try{
                            String query = "SELECT * FROM SERVICE";
                            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
                            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","hai","admin");
                            Statement stm = con.createStatement();
                            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(query);

                            while(rs.next())
                            {
                                %>
                                <option value="<%=rs.getInt("serviceId")%>"><%=rs.getString("serviceName")%></option>
                                <%
                            }

                        }
                        catch(Exception ex){
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        %>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                Select Service Price:
                <select name="servicePrice">
                    <option selected="selected">select Price</option>
                    <%

                        try{
                            String sql = "SELECT * FROM SERVICE WHERE SERVICEID=?";
                            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
                            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","hai","admin");

                            PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                            psmt.setString(1,request.getParameter("service"));

                            ResultSet rs = psmt.executeQuery();
                            while(rs.next())
                            {
                                %>
                                <option value="<%=rs.getInt("serviceId")%>"><%=rs.getDouble("servicePrice") %></option>
                                <%
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        { 
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        %>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want the first dropdown list to connect with a second dropdown list. For Example, if I select a service name such as "dry cleaning", then the service price will come up automatically. I am using jsp, javascript and servlet.

Comment: Study MVC design pattern . This is totally wrong implementation.

Comment: ohh.. ok, Tq :)